# Two or More users pulling data from DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have an ASP.Net web application that calls a customer to a station. Five employees are running this application simultaneously when they see a customer walk in they click on a ButtonGetCustomer to call the customer and come to their station.

Here is my issue. I am getting the data from SQL and storing it in a Datatable. Sometimes when two or more clerks click at the same time they call the same customer.

Any ideas in how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Lock access to the data so that only one caller can be in the "call customer" code at a time.

Comment: @zimdanen any ideas how to implement this?

Comment: @Apollo how do you know when a customer is called? Can you show the sql table that stores this info?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev when a customer is called a DATE/TIME stamp is written to that record. What I do is check first if that customer has called written to it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problems with thousands of people clicking the same button trying to claim a limited number of spots. Here is a similar solution:

1. When they click your button, run a stored procedure to mark that user as seen.
2. Your SPROC will first check to see if the user is marked as seen, if so, quit (I use RAISEERROR and pass a message back and catch the SQL Exception in code so you can tell them what user has already been called).
3. If the user hasn't been seen, the next thing your SPROC does is mark them as seen.

So the person who clicked the button either has success and sees the customer, or he gets a message saying the customer has already been seen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is a [concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_%28computer_science%29) problem. Try wrapping the read of the datatable in a lock statement (there are several), the records you plan on returning to the calling thread should be flagged so that they are not picked up by other thread, try something **like** this:

```
private Object _syncObject = new Object();
private DataTable yourDataReadMethod() {
   lock(_syncObject)
   {
   // Read records to return to calling thread.

   // Flag records read so they are not given to other threads. You might need expiration date in case the records are not completed in a timely manner.
   }
}
```

Furthermore, if you are updating a record after a call takes place you should compare a the db last updated date with a date that is persisted in the client form; if they differ than raise an exception, because this means that someone else has already updated the record. Hopefully that helps.